# How to judge if two threads have accessed the same region of memory?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Imagine we have two threads of the same process, I want to know if the two threads communicate with each other. 
In other words, if the two threads access(read/write) the same region of memory, there is a correlation between them. 
To be more specific, the input is two different thread ids, the output is a boolean that indicates whether the two threads have accessed a same region of memory. Is there any tools or methods that can trace the memory accessing(read/write) operations of the two threads?

Comment: Since this is common behaviour in a multithreaded apps, I can't see the usefulnedss of such a tool, and so I doubt that it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding out whether two threads are accessing the same memory would be very difficult.  It would probably involve the use of virtualization, so that you can have code of yours invoked every single time one of the threads accesses memory, so as to see if this memory has also been accessed by the other thread.  This would in turn make the threads run so slow, that you might have to wait for a long time before each thread covers its working set.

Luckily, you don't need to do any of that stuff, because I can tell you what you would find if you tried it:

Within the same process, it is virtually guaranteed that any two threads will be accessing some of the same memory.  That's not necessarily because they are trying to communicate with each other, but due to various housekeeping reasons, such as keeping track of which thread is current, invoking common functions which need to keep some state on a per-thread basis, etc.

You, sir, have an x-y problem in your hands.  http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thank you so much. That gives me hints on both solving and defining my problem.